# What architecture can I use to change screens in Swift when there's an event outside of the current view?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, architecture

For example, I have a Notification that occurs when there is an "unauthorized" error returned from the api server that should bring the user back to the login screen.  This event could appear anywhere in the program.

Do I create a new viewless controller to manage states and have it monitor for this notification and then present the login view controller?

I'm thinking about push notifications too, received by the app delegate.  Some of these may cause the data model to get updated and then the screen to change.  Who should make the screen change?  In the past I put all this in the AppDelegate.  But there must be a more elegant way!

I also found out about FlowControllers.  But they don't play nicely with Interface Builder, at least according to [this solution](http://albertodebortoli.com/blog/2014/09/03/flow-controllers-on-ios-for-a-better-navigation-control/?utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_162&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly).

Please let me know if you need more specific information about my project.

Comment: In the past, I have embedded all view controllers inside a subclass of `UINavigationController` and used `NSNotification`s and observers in the subclass to trigger different segues by identifier.